# Best practice to shutdown SharePoint 2016/2019 farm to do a "cold" snapshot. How to handle Distributed cache?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, patching, distributedcache

Hello SharePoint Experts.

We want to perform a "cold" snapshot of our virtual SharePoint Servers and need to shutdown the servers before we will patch the farm.
As far as I understand there is no need for a specific order to shut down the servers, but it will minimize the error events if we do it in the following order:

1. WebFrontEnd Servers
2. App Servers (If there are more than one App servers the one with the Central Administration last)
3. SQL Server

Is it also necessary to stop the search services before shutting down and to run the script provided by microsoft to gracefully shutdown the distributed cache hosts?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/manage-the-distributed-cache-service#perform-a-graceful-shutdown-of-the-distributed-cache-service-by-using-a-powershell-script

Are there any suggestions to do before we start the patching?

Thank you very much in advance and kind regards,

DocZito

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, there is no specific order in which you need to shutdown your farm (or bring it up).

Because you're shutting down all servers, you can skip the script. AppFab will resolve the unallocated cache fractions when you bring up your DC(s).

Provided you're running 2016 or 2019, I would skip the snapshot step. Patching failures are incredibly rare. In fact, we patch SharePoint 2016 during business hours and have done so for 2 years now without issues on a monthly basis.

Comment: Hello Trevor, thank you very much for your answer. Just to confirm: I can just shutdown one server after the other without care about the distributed cache service that is running on them and boot them up again after doing the snapshot? We do not have any backup at all at the moment so we want to do the snapshot to have a "backup" before we have a backup strategy in place.

Comment: I am just asking because I found this other answer from you but I am not sure if this a different case or not: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b0cadaba-6f60-4995-9f28-7d4accd6c71b/rebooting-sharepoint-servers-and-distributed-cache-servers?forum=SP2016